# Is SQL Server service enabled for Iron Foundry v2?

Tags: cloud, cloud-foundry

I setup dea_ng and Warden server and deployed simple ASP.NET MVC app to Iron Foundry v2 on top of my Cloud Foundry v2, which was setup with the help of [cf_nise_installer](https://github.com/yudai/cf_nise_installer). The question is - how can I enable the SQL Server as a Cloud Foundry service to be provisioned for my .NET apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see now, there was no support for MS SQL Server for Cloud Foundry v2 from Iron Foundry side. However now, since new [service broker API](http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/running/architecture/services/#api) is introduced, there appeared a possibility to implement one.

So, I could suggest looking at [.Net Cloud Foundry v2 services](https://github.com/Altoros/DotNetCloudFoundryServices) introduced by Altoros team. There is a general .Net service broker component, which translates REST API of service broker into c# interface and is possible to host both in IIS app and Windows service. Also there is an implementation of this interface for MS SQL Server, so it is now available for CFv2.